# Create banners in terminal mac

Tags: macos, terminal

[image]

How do you change command prompt in mac terminal so that it looks like above?
focused on this part: `se@macbook ~/Projects` where it has a triangle at the end

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use a character like ▶︎ (U+25b8), but it doesn't fill the whole block with at least Menlo:

[image]

If you change the prompt, surround non-printing characters with `\[` and `\]`:

```
PS1='\[\e[41m\]\w \[\e[31;44m\]▶︎\[\e[31m\] \[\e[m\] '
```

`\e[41m` sets the background to red, `\e[31;44m` sets the foreground to red and the background to blue, and `\e[m` resets colors. `\w` is the working directory.